# Implementing the 0.632+ bootstrap method using the Weka Java API

Tags: bootstrap, weka

I am trying to implement the 0.632+ bootstrap estimator (as proposed by [Efron and Tibshirani 1997](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1997.10474007#.U2o7MVdMzTo)) in order to perform certain benchmarks and compare it with other cross-validation methods, such as the *k*-fold CV.

Currently, all of my machine learning code is written in Java and all (sub)sampling, stratification, machine learning, and cross-validation is performed using the WEKA Java API. Therefore I would also like to implement this estimator using the same API.

I have performed an extensive search and haven't found any useful algorithm or pseudocode regarding the 0.632+ estimator. Unfortunately, I am unable to *decypher* the original paper and rewrite the mathematical formulas into software code.

Could please someone explain the basic steps that are needed in order to perform the 0.632+ estimator?

Currently, the only thing that I have implemented is the basic (0.632??) bootstrap method, in which I sample *n* instances (with replacement) from a dataset containing *n* instances. Then, in average, I get the train set, containing 63.2% (unique) instances from the dataset. And the missed-out instances are assigned to the test set.

Do I get it right until this part?

Then, as far as I can understand, I have to measure the training error. This is where I get lost. I have a Computer Science background (if this even matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have managed to rewrite the Bootstrap 0.632+ from R to Java using the Weka Java API. The original R function can be found in the `bootpred` method inside the `bootstrap` package ([link](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/bootstrap/docs/bootpred)).

As you can see from the source code, I have used the corrected $\hat{R'}$ and $\hat{Err}^{(1)'}$ with the final (corrected) equation `(32)` from the [original article](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1997.10474007#.U2o7MVdMzTo).

However, despite correcting for abnormal values, I sometimes still get negative error rate, which is of course impossible and therefore invalid. Also, I have noticed that the difference between the `0.632` and the `0.632+` method is minimal, if any.

If someone finds any errors in my source code, I would be really grateful if you could point them out.

```
public class Bootstrap632plus extends AbstractPerformance {

    private final int repeats;
    private double Err632;
    private double resub;

    public Bootstrap632plus(Instances instances, int repeats) {
        super(instances);
        this.repeats = repeats;
    }

    public double getErr632() {
        return Err632;
    }

    public double getResub() {
        return resub;
    }

    @Override
    public double getErrorRate(final MachineLearningAlgorithm machineLearningAlgorithm, final Random seed) throws Exception {

        // First component
        double err = predictionError(machineLearningAlgorithm);
        this.resub = err;

        // Error rates
        List<Double> errorRates = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

        // GAMA related stuff
        final int numClasses = instances.numClasses();
        AtomicIntegerArray p_l = new AtomicIntegerArray(numClasses);
        AtomicIntegerArray q_l = new AtomicIntegerArray(numClasses);

        // Bootstrap iterations
        seed.ints(repeats).parallel().forEach(randomSeed -> {

            // Get error rate
            Evaluation evaluation = bootstrapIteration(machineLearningAlgorithm, randomSeed);
            errorRates.add(evaluation.errorRate());

            /*
             GAMA VARIABLE

                Confusion matrix:
                 - first dimension (rows): real distribution for first class
                 - second dimension (columns): predicted distribution for first class

                p_l = observed proportions of responses where y_i equals l
                    - sum by l-th row (first dimension)

                q_l = observer proportions of predicted responses where y_i equals l
                    - sum by l-th column (second dimension)

                GAMA = SUM_by_l(p_l * (1 - q_l))

             */
            double[][] confusionMatrix = evaluation.confusionMatrix();

            for(int l = 0; l < numClasses; l++) {

                int p_tmp = 0, q_tmp = 0;

                for(int n = 0; n < numClasses; n++) {

                    // Sum for l-th class
                    p_tmp += confusionMatrix[l][n];
                    q_tmp += confusionMatrix[n][l];

                }

                // Add data for l-th class
                p_l.addAndGet(l, p_tmp);
                q_l.addAndGet(l, q_tmp);

            }

        });

        // Second component
        double Err1 = errorRates.stream().mapToDouble(i -> i).average().orElse(0);

        // Plain 0.632 bootstrap
        Err632 = .368*err + .632*Err1;

        // GAMA
        final double observations = instances.size() * repeats;
        double gama = 0;
        for(int l = 0; l < numClasses; l++) {

            // Normalize numbers -> divide by number of all observations (repeats * dataset size)
            gama += ((double)p_l.get(l) / observations) * (1 - ((double)q_l.get(l) / observations));

        }

        // Relative overfitting rate (R)
        double R = (Err1 - err) / (gama - err);

        // Modified variables (according to original journal article)
        double Err1_ = Double.min(Err1, gama);
        double R_ = R;

        // R can fall out of [0, 1] -> set it to 0
        if(!(Err1 > err && gama > err)) {
            R_ = 0;
        }

        // The 0.632+ bootstrap (as used in original article)
        double Err632plus = Err632 + (Err1_ - err) * (.368 * .632 * R_) / (1 - .368 * R_);

        return Err632plus;

    }

    /**
     * Prediction error: first component of the 0.632+ bootstrap.
     * Train the classifier on the whole dataset and then also test it on the whole dataset.
     * 
     * @param machineLearningAlgorithm Specified machine learning algorithm
     * @return prediction error [0, 1]
     * @throws Exception exception
     */
    private double predictionError(final MachineLearningAlgorithm machineLearningAlgorithm) throws Exception {

        // Train
        Classifier classifier = ClassifierFactory.instantiate(machineLearningAlgorithm);
        classifier.buildClassifier(instances);

        // Test
        Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(instances);
        evaluation.evaluateModel(classifier, instances);

        // Return error rate
        return evaluation.errorRate();

    }

    /**
     * One iteration of the Leave-one-out Bootstrap Cross-Validation.
     * @return
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    private Evaluation bootstrapIteration(final MachineLearningAlgorithm machineLearningAlgorithm, final int randomSeed) {

        try {

            final int SIZE = instances.size();
            final Random r = new Random(randomSeed);

            // Custom sampling (100%, with replacement)
            List<Instance> TRAIN = new ArrayList<>(SIZE); // Empty list (add one-by-one)
            List<Instance> TEST = new ArrayList<>(instances); // Full (remove one-by-one)

            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {

                // Random select instance
                Instance instance = instances.get(r.nextInt(SIZE));

                // Add to TRAIN, remove from TEST
                TRAIN.add(instance);
                TEST.remove(instance);

            }

            // Train
            Instances trainSet = new Instances(instances, TRAIN.size());
            trainSet.addAll(TRAIN);

            Classifier classifier = ClassifierFactory.instantiate(machineLearningAlgorithm);
            classifier.buildClassifier(trainSet);

            // Test set
            Instances testSet = new Instances(instances, TEST.size());
            testSet.addAll(TEST);

            // Test
            Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(instances);
            evaluation.evaluateModel(classifier, testSet);

            // Return the evaluation (for further processing)
            return evaluation;

        } catch(Exception e) {

            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer but I see 2 problems in your code: 1. the `bootstrapIteration` method evaluates the model on the samples not in the training set (i.e. out of the bootstrap sample). If you look at the R code in `bootpred`, you can clearly see that they evaluate each model on the whole dataset (this is the line with `yhat2`). In fact, you can reconstruct the variable `yhat1` (which is the error on the bootstrap sample) from this `yhat2` (for instance with the variables $N_i^b$ and $N_i^b$ defined in the article). 2. you compute $\hat{\gamma}$ with the for

Comment: Thank you for your input. Regarding #1: I was referring to [http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96739/what-is-the-632-rule-in-bootstrapping](this) post, where the train and test datasets are strictly separated (as they should be). The only exception is when I calculate the resubstitution rate. Regarding #2: I am only using n-ary classification, so I don't face the problems that you mentioned. Regarding implementation: I myself am not confident if the implementation is correct, so I cannot give you a confident answer.

Answer (score 1):

The 0.632 and 0.632+ bootstraps were necessary because a discontinuous improper accuracy score (proportion classified correctly) was being used.  If you use a proper accuracy score, the ordinary Efron-Gong optimism bootstrap works just fine, and is much easier to program.

Comment: I am doing a research on comparison of CV and bootstrap methods. Currently, I have selected the following methods: train/test split (ratio: 80/20), 10-fold CV, 10-fold repeated CV (5 repeats), bootstrap 0.632, and bootstrap 0.632+. I am comparing all selected methods by bias (I also calculate the true error rate), variability and CPU time. I have selected the mentioned methods because I found them being mentioned in several papers. I will also look into your suggested method - at this stage, I still have the option to change my selected methods.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't have enough reputation to comment (even on the question) so it's the only way to try to help you. You are right for point 1: you don't need to evaluate on the whole dataset for the 0.632 or 0.632+ bootstrap (it's needed for the optimist bootstrap). However, there is another problem with your code: you compute the `gama` variable (which should be spelled `gamma` BTW) for every bootstrap iteration while in fact it only uses the output of the model trained and tested on the whole dataset (named $r_{\mathbf{x}}$ in the article). It's a bit complicated to understand that from the article but this is how I implemented it and how it is implemented in the [Daim package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Daim/) (look for function Daim). Therefore you can compute `gamma` in function `predictionError` if it's possible to return two `double` or just return the `evaluation` variable and compute the apparent error rate and `gamma` in `getErrorRate`.

Comment: @alesc: I wanted to test your code in weka but I don't know how to proceed. Do you have any clue? I have grep trough weka 3.6.10 (default in Ubuntu 14.04) but haven't found any class named `AbstractInterface`. Which version do you use?

Comment: @alesc Any news?